# how to get RETURN_GENERATED_KEY in spring mvc to another table?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, jdbctemplate

I have generated key but i'm trying to insert in two tables with auto_generated_key of first table as input value in second table. Here are my two table employeedetail(master table) and login(child table) connected with foreign key employeeid.

```
public employeebean insertData(employeebean bean){
                KeyHolder keyholder= new GeneratedKeyHolder();
         Template.update(new PreparedStatementCreator(){
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException{
            PreparedStatement statement=null;               
                statement= con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employeedetail(employeename,employeeage,employeeaddress,employeedepartmentid) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                statement.setString(1,bean.getEmployeename());
                statement.setInt(2,bean.getEmployeeage());
                statement.setString(3,bean.getEmployeeaddress());
                statement.setInt(4,bean.getEmployeedepartmentid());
                return statement;
            }           
        },keyholder);

        int newemployeeid= keyholder.getKey().intValue();
        bean.setEmployeeid(newemployeeid);
        System.out.println(newemployeeid);


        return bean;
    }
```

i want newemployeeid to be inserted in login table automatically. I've no idea how to do this. Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Are you using JDBCTemplate?

Comment: yeah JdbcTemplate

Comment: What is the value you are getting in `newemployeeid`?

Comment: Most recent auto generated employeeid when i insert.

Comment: You are getting the auto-generated key for `employeedetail` table, right? So what is your actual problem? You are returning the `employeebean` which has newly created id, you can use it to insert into `login` table.

Comment: Now i'm trying to insert this auto_generated_id in login(child) table but not manually. but how can i insert, i'm new to spring. i have did this before in J2EE but i've no idea with spring